# Is my data eligible for PCA?

Tags: correlation, pca, factor-analysis, factor-rotation

I have a data set in which each subject answered a subset of questions in response to visual stimuli (picture rating). At the beginning of the experiment, every subject got assigned 2 out of 16 questions, on which a large set of images was rated. I do not have measures of all 16 variables from all subjects.

My question now is: Can I do a PCA on the 16 questions even though I only have within subject variation for 2 out of 16?

Comment: I don't really follow your situation. What would be the point of running a PCA? Are you trying to predict what subjects would have rated each image, if they had seen it? Are you wondering if the images get similar ratings? Something else?

Comment: The goal was to check whether the 16 variables on which the images were rated can be collapsed into underlying components.